# tree-dvips Alternative for Linguistics Document with pdftex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, linguistics, avm

I'm attempting to find a way of linking two objects in avm.sty together. The result I want is exactly that specified here: http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/avms/#4

I'm using pdftex so tree-dvips does not work. How can the same effect be achieved in pdftex? I assume it could be done with tikz, but I cannot for the life of me work out how.

Sample code is here:

```
\begin{avm}
\[{} PRED `avoid <SUBJ, OBJ>'; TNS $\neq$ PAST \\
     TOPIC \[ PRED `kind<COMP>' \\
                    DEF +; LOC FAR; NUM SG \\
                    COMP \[ PRED `of <OBJ>' \\
                            OBJ \[ PRED `cake'\] \] \] \\
     SUBJ \[ PRED `pro'; NUM SG; PERS 1; CASE NOM\] \\
     OBJ \[ $\qquad$ \] \\
     ADJ \[ PRED `usually'\] \]
\end{avm}
```

A tree-dvips implementation would be as follows:

```
\begin{avm}
\[{} PRED `avoid <SUBJ, OBJ>'; TNS $\neq$ PAST \\
     \node{topic}{TOPIC \[ PRED `kind<COMP>' \\
                    DEF +; LOC FAR; NUM SG \\
                    COMP \[ PRED `of <OBJ>' \\
                            OBJ \[ PRED `cake'\] \] \]} \\
     SUBJ \[ PRED `pro'; NUM SG; PERS 1; CASE NOM\] \\
     \node{object}{OBJ \[ $\qquad$ \]} \\
     ADJ \[ PRED `usually'\] \]
\end{avm}
\nodecurve[r]{topic}[r]{object}{2in}
```

The best I've been able to come up with using tikz is:

```
\begin{avm}
\[{} PRED `avoid <SUBJ, OBJ>'; TNS $\neq$ PAST \\
     \tikz \node (topic) {TOPIC \[ PRED `kind<COMP>' \\
                    DEF +; LOC FAR; NUM SG \\
                    COMP \[ PRED `of <OBJ>' \\
                            OBJ \[ PRED `cake'\] \] \]}; \\
     SUBJ \[ PRED `pro'; NUM SG; PERS 1; CASE NOM\] \\
     \tikz \node (object) {OBJ \[ $\qquad$ \]}; \\
     ADJ \[ PRED `usually'\] \] \tikz \node (viapoint) {};
\end{avm}

\tikz[overlay] \draw[-] (topic) to[out=0,in=90  ] (viapoint)
                        (viapoint) to[out=270,in=0] (object);
```

However this results in two disconnected lines, one of which goes through other text.

Any help on improvement would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you posted complete compilable documents rather than fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `tikzmark` library. (Documented separately: `texdoc tikzmark` will show its documentation.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{avm}
\[{} PRED `avoid <SUBJ, OBJ>'; TNS $\neq$ PAST \\
      TOPIC \[ PRED `kind<COMP>' \\
                    DEF +; LOC FAR; NUM SG \\
                    COMP \[ PRED `of <OBJ>' \\
                            OBJ \[ PRED `cake'\] \] \]\tikzmark{topic} \\
     SUBJ \[ PRED `pro'; NUM SG; PERS 1; CASE NOM\] \\
      OBJ \[ $\qquad$ \]\tikzmark{object} \\
     ADJ \[ PRED `usually'\] \]
\end{avm}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
    \draw[-] (pic cs:topic) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2]  (pic cs:object);

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]