# tikz draws line in wrong place (2 pages above its definition)

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikzmark

I am trying to get tikz to draw a line between nodes inside an attribute-value matrix defined using the `avm` package. For this, I am using `\tikzmark` as described in the answer here: [tree-dvips Alternative for Linguistics Document with pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120316/tree-dvips-alternative-for-linguistics-document-with-pdftex)

Curiously, this does not work for the AVM below. For whatever reason, the line is drawn two pages above its definition. As should be obvious from the MWE, I'd like to connect the whole `SUBJ` AVM to the word 'apna'. Anyone have an idea?

EDIT#1: I have slightly changed the MWE and removed unnecessary packages. What's strange is that if I compile the code in a separate file, it draws the line in the right place, but within the larger document the line appears two pages above its definition. What could be causing such behavior?

EDIT#2: @JohnKormylo Thanks! The line is drawn perfectly fine now that I define it inside the figure. No idea why a) this would make any difference in the first place, and b) why I would not have to pay attention to this if I place the code in a separate document.

EDIT#3: A (minor) follow-up question: How do I get the line to connect at type height? In the example above, it is the case that the line connects to the bottom right of the word 'apna', not at the center right.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{avm}
\[ PRED & `gari$<$($\uparrow$~SUBJ)$>$'\\
SUBJ & \[ PRED & `nina'\\
CASE & gen\\
GEND & fem\\
PERS & 3\\
NUM & sg\\
CHECK & \[
NMORPH & obl\\
\]
\]\tikzmark{ante3}\\
ADJUNCT & \{ \[ PRED & `apna'\tikzmark{ana3}\\
GEND & fem\\
NUM & sg\\
CHECK & \[
NMORPH & nom\\
\]\\
ATYPE & reflexive\\
\]
\}\\
CASE & nom\\
GEND & fem\\
PERS & 3\\
NUM & sg\\
NTYPE & common\\
CHECK & \[
NMORPH & nom\\
\]
\]
\end{avm}
\caption{NP f-structure, common noun head, reflexive binding}
\label{fs-poss-bind-ex-3}
\end{figure}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
    \draw[-] (pic cs:ante3) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2]  (pic cs:ana3);

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling your code _twice_?

Comment: Yes, I have. It seems that this is necessary for all things drawn by `tikz`, correct?

Comment: No, it is necessary only because of `remember picture,overlay`: at the first run the position is stored and then the `\path` is actually drawn. Usually `tikzpicture`s compile at the first go. However, this was just the first check, now I'll try to look into your code.

Comment: Please complete your code so that it will compile and remove any unnecessary packages.

Comment: Can you put the second \tikz inside the figure as well, or is that the point?

Comment: @SebastianSulger Your MWE is to minimal : no problem with it. Add `\usepackage{lipsum}` in your preamble and `\lipsum[2-4]` before your figure to exhibit your problem.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You have found the solution!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks! The line is drawn perfectly fine now that I define it inside the figure. No idea why a) this would make any difference in the first place, and b) why I would not have to pay attention to this if I place the code in a separate document.

Comment: A (minor) follow-up question: How do I get the line to connect at type height? In the example above, it is the case that the line connects to the bottom right of the word 'apna', not at the center right.

Comment: You could always put the \tikzmark inside a \raisebox, or use the calc library and ($(pic cs:ana)+(0,.5ex)$).

Comment: Found the documentation; you can also use ([shift=(0pt,0.5ex)]pic cs:ana)

Comment: @JohnKormylo `([shift=(0pt,0.5ex)]pic cs:ana)` does not work for me. TeX reports the following: `!Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/0.5ex)' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: oops, ([shift={(0pt,0.5ex)}]pic cs:ana3)

Comment: @JohnKormylo Great stuff, thanks! If you like, post your answer - or would you like me to do it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{avm}
\[ PRED & `gari$<$($\uparrow$~SUBJ)$>$'\\
SUBJ & \[ PRED & `nina'\\
CASE & gen\\
GEND & fem\\
PERS & 3\\
NUM & sg\\
CHECK & \[
NMORPH & obl\\
\]
\]\tikzmark{ante3}\\
ADJUNCT & \{ \[ PRED & `apna'\tikzmark{ana3}\\
GEND & fem\\
NUM & sg\\
CHECK & \[
NMORPH & nom\\
\]\\
ATYPE & reflexive\\
\]
\}\\
CASE & nom\\
GEND & fem\\
PERS & 3\\
NUM & sg\\
NTYPE & common\\
CHECK & \[
NMORPH & nom\\
\]
\]
\end{avm}
\caption{NP f-structure, common noun head, reflexive binding}
\label{fs-poss-bind-ex-3}
%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
    \draw[-] (pic cs:ante3) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2]  (pic cs:ana3);
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Just a note for those coming to this answer later: as mentioned in the comments, the necessary change was to include the \tikz drawing commands inside the figure as well. When a float migrates between pages, the tikz commands do not migrate with it, so they end up drawing on whatever page they are executed on. By putting them inside the figure, they are moved along with the rest of the float to the new page.